# remotely accessing VisualSVN repository using TortoiseSVN through DYNDNS

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, dyndns

I am trying remotely access my repository through DynDNS and updating the Dynamic Address through their client.  Locally, I can checkout, Import, ETC. using TortoiseSVN, but for the life of me, I can NOT access my repository remotely.  What is the syntax for accessing the repository remotely?  I've tried:

https://.dyndns.biz/svn
https://.dyndns.biz/svn//trunk

also using the IP address with and without the port number, svn://, http:// and many variations.  Can anybody tell me how to set up TortoiseSVN correctly and give me the correct URL syntax to access my repositories remotely.  Oh, and then blog it with pictures, because I can't find the correct answer anywhere.

Using:
VisualSVN Server (free)
TortoiseSVN (free)
DynDNS (free)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way it used to work for me:

When you signed up for a DynDNS account you had to give your site a name, let's assume robsapko.dyndns.biz.

You must also set up something that will update your DynDNS account with your ISP-provided IP address on a regular basis.  Since I use Linux I downloaded ddclient and set it up via a crontab entry to run on the DynDNS-recommended schedule (once an hour, IIRC).

Then, you must punch a hole through your firewall to accept incoming requests on port 443 (https default port) and redirect them to your VisualSVN server.

After you've done both of those then https: communications to https://robsapko.dyndns.biz will get your updated IP address from DynDNS, attempt to connect to your IP address, be redirected by your firewall configuration to your VisualSVN server and you should be successful.

The exact URL depends upon your repository configuration.

If you connect locally as https://svnserver/svn/myrepo then you would connect remotely as https://robsapko.dyndns.biz/svn/myrepo.

Hope this helps!

edit:  Be aware that this opens your VisualSVN server to the entire world.  Anyone could sniff or probe your machine.  When I did this I set up iptables entries on my Linux box that only allowe incoming connections from my local network addresses and my work subnet.  I considered it unlikely that I'd hack myself or that someone from work would hack me.  You have been warned.  Standard disclaimers apply.